# Homeomorphisms with quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm finding some problems in solving this exercise: let $X=[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and $A= \left \{ 0 \right \} \times [0,1]$.

1. Show that $X/A=\left ([0,1] \times [0,1]  \right )/ \left ( \left \{ 0 \right \} \times [0,1]  \right )$ is homeomorphic to a triangle.
2. Show that $X/A$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

Regarding point 1, my goal is to answer without using compactness, writing a continuos and bijective function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, where $Y$ is a triangle, constant on the equivalente classes of $X/A$. This implies that the function $[f]: X/A \rightarrow Y$ is continuos and bijective too. Since the composition $f= [f] \circ \pi$ is commutative (where $\pi$ is the natural projection) I'll have to show that also $f^{-1}$ is continuos, and then $[f]^{-1}$ is continuos too. Hence $[f]$ is an homeomorphism.

How to formalise all this? I need a general method, so that I can solve point 2 by myself.

Comment: Did you make a picture ?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the quotient space should be an isosceles triangle inscribed in the unit square. So, do I have to write down a homeomorphism between $X/A$ and this triangle?But how to do that? Using polar coordinates?

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** Try to prove that the function $g : X \rightarrow X$ defined by
$$g(x,y)=(x,xy)$$

defines a injection $\tilde{g} : X/A \rightarrow X$, and show that $\tilde{g}$ is a homeomorphism between $X/A$ and the triangle of vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Ok, since $g$ is continuos, bijective and on the components $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ is constant: $g(0,0)=g(0,1)=(0,0)$ (is it right?), then $\tilde{g}$ is continuos. Now let's consider $g^{-1}: X \rightarrow X$, defined by $g^{-1}=(x,y/x)$...is this the inverse of $g$? If yes, there's a problem at $(0,0)$. Anyway, if $g^{-1}$ is continuous I'm done.

Comment: Regarding point 2, is it correct to take $g(x,y)=(x,y)$?

Comment: Actually, you have to verify the following points : 1) $\overline{g}$ is well-defined (i.e. why does $g$ define a map on $X/A$ ?) 2) $\overline{g}$ is continuous (this is easy since $g$ is continuous) 3)  $\overline{g}$ is bijective : the easiest way is to prove that every element of $X$ has a unique preimage by  $\overline{g}$. Then if you prove these two points, you have then that  $\overline{g}$ is a homeomorphism since $X/A$ is compact